# UIImage displays blue rectangle instead of JPEG image

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, uiimage

I'm an iOS, iOS development and Swift newbie.

I would like to have a Bar Button with an icon. It should display the user's Facebook avatar. The avatar from Facebook is in JPEG format.

This is what I have so far:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var userButton: UIBarButtonItem!

var user: User?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.user = UserClient.sharedInstance.user
    println(self.user?.pictureUrl)

    if let pictureUrl = self.user?.pictureUrl {

        let url = NSURL(string: pictureUrl)
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
        userButton.image = UIImage(data: data!) 
    }
}
...
```

The problem: It displays a blue rectangle instead of the user's avatar.

[image: It displays a blue rectangle instead of the user's avatar]

My initial thoughts:

1. Either userButton.image is simply not the correct property
2. ... or I need to convert the image
3. ... or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either set the background image instead with setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:, or you can use setImage, but you have to explicitly set the image's rendering mode to UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal (what you're seeing is a template image).

```
if let pictureUrl = self.user?.pictureUrl {

    let url = NSURL(string: pictureUrl)
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    let img = UIImage(data: data!)
    let originalImage = img!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
    userButton.image =  originalImage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

also you can use image as background:

```
userButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"3.jpg"), forState: .Normal)
```